# SQL multiple joins on same table such that an entity has all fields set

Tags: sql, join, relational-database

I have the following table (it's a list of bannerids and available sizes for each):

```
bannerid, bannersize
--------------------
1, 16
1, 32
1, 128
2, 16
2, 32
2, 128
2, 256
2, 512
3, 16
3, 32
3, 64
3, 128
3, 256
3, 512
3, 1024
```

I need to be able to generate a list of all bannerid that have all the possible sizes (16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024)

So in this example, the result should be:

```
bannerid
--------
3
```

Since bannerid 3 has all the possible sizes as mentioned above (1 and 2 were missing few sizes).

What's a good way to achieve this?  I assume there's a better way than doing a join 7 times on the same table and checking that every possible size combination exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select bannerid, count(bannersize) 
from tbl_banners  
where bannersize in (16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024) 
group by bannerid  
having count(bannersize) = 7 ;
```

Comment: +1 - That's good -- it takes my query, but removes the possibly faulty assumption by checking the bannersize.

Comment: That worked beautifully, as it also allows me to adjust if I want to match all 7 sizes or only any 6 of them.

Comment: @Max, Also, would you know how do I run that query if I want to see all the bannerids displayed (without grouping them by bannerid)?  

So, like in the example above I would see 7 bannerid lines, each with different size.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT bannerid
     FROM tbl
 GROUP BY bannerid
   HAVING COUNT(bannersize) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bannersize) FROM tbl)
```

This works if you needed `bannerid` of complete sets **regardless** of what `bannersizes` will exist in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select bannerid
from t
group by bannerid
where count(distinct bannersize) = 7
```